# heroku db:pull not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, sequel

```
heroku db:pull postgresql://root:@localhost/db_name
```

After this command display this message

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:50: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future version
Loaded Taps v0.3.13
Warning: Data in the database 'postgresql://root:@localhost/db_name' will be overwritten and will not be recoverable.
Are you sure you wish to continue? (y/n)? y
Failed to connect to database:
  Sequel::AdapterNotFound -> LoadError: no such file to load -- sequel/adapters/postgresql

How to use db:pull

Answer (score 12):

First, you need to fix your connection string: use `postgres` instead of `postgresql`.

You will need to have the `pg` db adapter installed to use [Sequel's postgresql adapter](http://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb):

```
gem install pg
```

You may also want to make sure your taps, sequel, and heroku gems are up to date:

```
gem install heroku taps sequel
```

Then try your `heroku db:pull` again. If that doesn't work, post a comment or hop in #heroku on Freenode and we can try to help.

Answer (score 2):

Your connection string is wrong.  Try:

```
heroku db:pull postgres://root:@localhost/db_name
```

Comment: Jeremy is right, totally missed that you used 'postgresql' instead of 'postgres'.

Comment: I had to use a connection URL in the command like this: `heroku db:pull postgres://@localhost/my_local_db` -- in other words I didn't have a user named root.

Answer (score 0):

Started working fine once I upgraded the "pg" gem from version "0.11.0" to "0.12.2".