# Failed to connect to database - can't push PostgreSQL database to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, postgresql-9.1

I created a very simple blog app with a couple of entries and all I'm trying to do is push it to heroku, but I get the following error:

```
$ heroku db:push [git@github.com:appname/blog.git]
Loaded Taps v0.3.24
Auto-detected local database: postgres://benjaminw@127.0.0.1/blog_development?en
coding=WIN1252
Warning: Data in the app 'afternoon-taiga-2755' will be overwritten and will not
be recoverable.

!    WARNING: Destructive Action
!    This command will affect the app: afternoon-taiga-2755
!    To proceed, type "afternoon-taiga-2755" or re-run this command with --conf
irm afternoon-taiga-2755

> afternoon-taiga-2755
Failed to connect to database:
Sequel::AdapterNotFound -> LoadError: cannot load such file -- pg
```

But I've got the pg gem installed and the sequel gem installed.  Here is my gemfile.  I've excluded a few lines because they were commented out.  Has anyone ran into this problem?

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

 gem 'pg'
 gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter'
 gem 'sequel'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: Taps is not the recommended way by heroku anymore, did you try that : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Comment: Hmm...I'll read through the tutorial and give it a try.  Thanks

Comment: Ok let me know if you have any questions then

Comment: How does `config/database.yml` look like? Did you change anything in it?

Comment: @pjam I created a blog_development.dump file in my root directory folder of my app and I'm assuming I need to use the pgbackups:restore to upload it.  Is that right...can you clear this up a little?

Comment: That's right, thing is that they say you should upload it to s3 or any other service in order to import it, but maybe you try using your local server URL which should be something like `postgres://localhost/<YOUR DATABASE NAME>`. You can try with this other command `heroku pg:transfer --from <DATABASE_URL> --to jade --confirm <APP NAME>`. It really sucks that heroku doesnt have a clear and easy way to upload database. Anyway, try that, and let me know. You might also want to read this http://www.higherorderheroku.com/articles/pgtransfer-is-the-new-taps/

Comment: Just a side note, `jade` in the previous example is the color of your database, that you can find with `heroku config | grep POSTGRES`

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue with db:pull. After making sure I had all the gems installed, it worked (with a hat tip to: [heroku db:pull not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841237/heroku-dbpull-not-working)).

`gem install pg heroku taps sequel`